# Intune Win32 app package powershell script reports failed but ran successfully

Tags: powershell, deployment, intune

I have packaged a ps1 script with printer drivers to an intune w32 app package. The deployment is working successfully and installing the drivers but reports in the W10 Toast notifications and within Intune admin console that it failed.

Scanning through the logs, could this be because the Detection rule is still not satisfied at the end of the script running? If so what do you recommend to get accurate success/fail return codes for a .ps1 installation deployment? Is there a better solution for detection rules which are mandatory or a simple create folder/file/registry entry at the end of the script and assign detection rule to look for that?

Intune App package settings:

Install command: powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file PrinterDrivers.ps1

Uninstall command: powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file PrinterDrivers.ps1

Install behavior: System

Device restart behavior: App install may force a device restart

Return codes:

- 0 Success
- 1707 Success
- 3010 Soft reboot
- 1641 Hard reboot
- 1618 Retry

Rules format: Manually configure detection rules

Detection rules: Registry Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Random

Script content:

```
$PrinterDriver = @()
$PrinterDriver += @{DriverName="KONICA MINOLTA C287SeriesPCL";DriverPath="$PSScriptRoot\Konica Minolta\C287";DriverInf="$PSScriptRoot\Konica Minolta\C287\KOAXPJ__.INF"}
$PrinterDriver += @{DriverName="KONICA MINOLTA C3100P PCL6";DriverPath="$PSScriptRoot\Konica Minolta\C3100p";DriverInf="$PSScriptRoot\Konica Minolta\C3100P\KOBK3J__.inf"}
$PrinterDriver += @{DriverName="KONICA MINOLTA C3110 PCL6";DriverPath="$PSScriptRoot\Konica Minolta\C3110";DriverInf="$PSScriptRoot\Konica Minolta\C3110\KOBK4J__.inf"}
$PrinterDriver += @{DriverName="RICOH Aficio SP C232SF PCL 6";DriverPath="$PSScriptRoot\Ricoh\C232SF";DriverInf="$PSScriptRoot\Ricoh\C232SF\PCL6.INF"}
$PrinterDriver += @{DriverName="RICOH Aficio SP C242SF PCL 6";DriverPath="$PSScriptRoot\Ricoh\C242SF";DriverInf="$PSScriptRoot\Ricoh\C242SF\PCL6.INF"}
$PrinterDriver += @{DriverName="RICOH SP C262SFNw PCL 6";DriverPath="$PSScriptRoot\Ricoh\C262SFNw";DriverInf="$PSScriptRoot\Ricoh\C262SFNw\PCL6.INF"}
$PrinterDriver += @{DriverName="RICOH SP C252SF PCL 6";DriverPath="$PSScriptRoot\Ricoh\C252SF";DriverInf="$PSScriptRoot\Ricoh\C252SF\PCL6.INF"}

### Check Printer Driver Exists Then Add Driver ####

foreach ($Driver in $PrinterDriver)
{
$PrintDiverExists = Get-PrinterDriver -name $Driver.DriverName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if (!$printDiverExists)
{
cscript "C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prndrvr.vbs" -a -m $Driver.DriverName -h $Driver.DriverPath -i $Driver.DriverInf
}
}
```

Comment: Intune/Endpoint manager shows the following results on my test device
The application was not detected after installation completed successfully (0x87D1041C)

Comment: added another if statement to create a folder and blank txt file to track versioning


$Path = "C:\ProgramData\PrinterDrivers"
If (!(Test-Path $Path))
{
md $Path
}
New-Item $Path\V1_deployed.txt -ItemType file